# How can I put javascript variable into Url.Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a post that work well when I run from VS2015 debug:

```
        $("#DisplayChartType").bind("change", function () {
            $.post("../Employee/ChangeDisplayChartType", { displayChartType: $("#DisplayChartType").val() }, function (data) {
                iDependOnMyParameter(data);
            })
        });
```

But post does not work once I have published to IIS. I tried using ../, / and ~/ in the post but none work. I searched web and found the approach below but I still get ARG1 being sent as a parameter instead of my javascript variable.

```
        $("#DisplayChartType").bind("change", function () {
            $.post("@Html.Action("ChangeDisplayChartType", "Employee", new { displayChartType = "ARG1" })".replace("ARG1",$("#DisplayChartType").val()) , function (data) {
                iDependOnMyParameter(data);
            })
        });
```

How should I do this? I really would like to stay with $.post approach as that works nicely in VS.

Comment: Seems weird to use post and use a querystring. If you switched to GET, it will be added to the querystring.

Comment: instead of trying this workaround I would investigate why your code is not working once published in IIS. Can you check the address called by the post?

Comment: `bind` is deprecated. You should use `on` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OJ Raqueno put me on the right path.

At top of script I now declare "myPath". My website URL ends with "secure" so this test gives me the right path:

```
    var myPath = document.URL;
    if (!myPath.endsWith("secure")) {
        myPath = "";
    }
```

Then I do this:

```
    $("#DisplayChartType").bind("change", function () {

        $.post(myPath + "/Employee/ChangeDisplayChartType", { displayChartType: $("#DisplayChartType").val() }, function (data) {
            alert($("#DisplayChartType").val());
            iDependOnMyParameter(data);
        })
    });
```

Comment: Glad to know I helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
  $("#DisplayChartType").bind("change", function () {
        var chartType = $("#DisplayChartType").val();
        var url="@Url.Action("ChangeDisplayChartType", "Employee", new { displayChartType = "ARG1" })";
        $.post(url.replace("ARG1", chartType), function (data) {
            iDependOnMyParameter(data);
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So add it to the url

```
$.post("../Employee/ChangeDisplayChartType?displayChartType=" + encodeURIComponent($("#DisplayChartType").val()), function(){});
```

or change your original code to GET and the value will be added to the querystring.

Comment: Like I put in question ../Employee or /Employee or ~/Employee do NOT work when published to IIS

Comment: `$.post("@Html.Action("ChangeDisplayChartType", "Employee", new { displayChartType = "ARG1" })" + "?displayChartType="" + encodeURIComponent...`

Comment: Or look at what that produces when you view the source and use the same thing in your post....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.origin` or `document.location.origin` to get the origin of your website, whether running in VS 2015 debug or on IIS.

So instead of doing

```
$.post("../Employee/ChangeDisplayChartType"
```

You can try

```
$.post(document.location.origin + "/Employee/ChangeDisplayChartType"
```

Comment: Almost! See my answer please